# Hadoop for data migration

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, data-migration, spring-batch, jcr

Most of cases I encountered were where data was being migrated in/out of HDFS. And I am entirely new to Hadoop!

But my requirement is to move large binary files from various sources in a single JCR compliant flat file repository. my question is

1) Is Hadoop a good choice for Read from X and write to Y (Both non HDFS systems) scenario?

2) Will any other custom framework or something like Spring batch will serve same purpose? Meaning it is just a problem of IO and network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use hadoop, if your X and Y can handle multiple connections and will give better performance if you retrieve and store data in parallel.

There is a framework called [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) that could  meet your needs better.

Comment: Thanks @Animesh. Squoop looks a good choice for databases, specially supported once. But not as great for BLOBs! Good lead though!

Comment: on a different track, I am trying to reach on your email with address given on your webpage, but getting failure delivery. Care to provide alternate email?

Comment: @Vishal Yeah you can mail me at : animesh.rajha@gmail.com